# Creating an API proxy in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating code from an existing WebApi 2 project and I am wondering how to perform the equivalent of the code below in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. I don't see any route code which accepts a handler option.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SomeApiProxy", "api/someapi/{*path}",
    handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpClientHandler(), new DelegatingHandler[] {new ForwardingProxyHandler(new Uri("http://some-api.com/api/v2/"))}),
    defaults: new {path = RouteParameter.Optional},
    constraints: null
);
```

Comment: Is it just get requests or any request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head but you could create a middleware. This would work for get requests with no headers but could be modified to do more.

```
app.Use( async ( context, next ) =>
{
    var pathAndQuery = context.Request.GetUri().PathAndQuery;

    const string apiEndpoint = "/api/someapi/";
    if ( !pathAndQuery.StartsWith( apiEndpoint ) )
        //continues through the rest of the pipeline
        await next();
    else
    {
        using ( var httpClient = new HttpClient() )
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync( "http://some-api.com/api/v2/" + pathAndQuery.Replace( apiEndpoint, "" ) );
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync( result );
        }
    }
} );
```

If you put this befire app.UseMvc() it will intercept any requests where the path starts with /api/someapi

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was able to expand on this and create a full middleware that does what I needed.

Comment: No problem am glad I could help

Comment: I tried to build that into something reusable for everyone. You can find it on GitHub here: https://github.com/ZoolWay/GlacierCrates.AspNetCore.ApiProxy

Comment: I have an internally hosted API but would like 3rd party to use it from outside the network? How would it work for my purpose? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002283/how-to-allow-internal-mvc-web-api-from-external-site-outside-the-network

Answer (score 3):

We actually wrote a middleware for this (well our intern did :)) https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it proxies all requests though. Am I missing something? I need to proxy certain requests based on the route/URL/request that is incoming. Either way, it is a helpful reference.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing! Just wanted to ask - does it have sockets problem described here (as creating new HttpClient()):
https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @ChrisPutnam . Use app.UseWhen  to pick and choose where/when you want it applied.  Proxy middleware worked great. Thumbs up to the intern